# How to call write() on a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a set of python classes that represent network data structures (and are also used for disk storage). I'd like to be able to call `write()` on the class and get its standard binary representation.

The classes can struct.pack themselves into a binary representation via a `pack()` method. I can overwrite the `__bytes__` method to call `self.pack()` so that `write(bytes(myobject))` will work, but not write (myobject):

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'MyClassName'
```

Is there something I can override to make `write()` work without the explicit `bytes()` cast? Possibly my class would have to be a subclass of Bytes but ... I presume I'd still have to hook up the `pack()` method call somehow?

Comment: Maybe you could wrap the stream and adapt it to call bytes first.

Comment: Are you just trying to save classes/objects to disk? Would pickle (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) work for you?

Comment: What's so bad about calling `bytes`? This seems like the best solution. Explicit is better than implicit. Now, what `write` is really expecting is an object that supports the buffer protocol. Unfortunately, I believe you have to write a C-extension to support this in your custom class.

Comment: Consider: https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/05/05/introduction-to-the-python-buffer-protocol/

Comment: Can't use pickle - it needs to match a predefined on disk format. 
I looked at the buffer code, seems staggeringly complex for a very simple problem - I just have an OrderedDict of (name, typename) pairs that match a C struct. Adding new ones as a derived class of my base PackedStruct type this way is trivial, just write out the struct as an OrderedDict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the class a subclass of `bytearray` and make any methods that can alter the object's value update the bytearray's value via the `__setitem__` method (that is, using square brackets):

```
class MyClassName(bytearray):
    def update(self):
        ''' a method that makes certain alterations to the object's value '''
        self[:] = self.pack()
```

Comment: You *could* do this, but that's probably not a good idea. Unless it makes sense for `MyClass` to *be* a bytearray. I'm not sure that this would work anyway, because what the `write` method is expecting is an object that supports the buffer protocol

Comment: By subclassing `bytearray` this class will certainly support the buffer protocol so it would work as the OP intends it to. The main downside to this approach is that it may be wasteful/inefficient to have potentially multiple calls to methods that update the `bytearray` value for several times before a `write` is actually called on this object. Ideally the `pack` method should be called only when a `write` is actually called.

Comment: yes, I skipped over the `self[:] = self.pack()`, but I still think that the major downside here is that `MyClass` shouldn't subclass `bytearray` unless it *is* a bytearray of sorts.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and update when I find out. It is a bytearray of sorts, it's a fixed data format structure that matches a packed C struct either on disk or network to allow Python to store data efficiently and intercommunicate with the main C code.